# stop form during submission if it validates incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to use JavaScript to validate forms but if the form doesn't validate, I don't want the form to be sent to the "action" page.

The validator:

```
<script>
    function formSubmit()
    {
    document.getElementById("signup_form").submit();
    var x=document.forms["signup_form"]["tname"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("First name must be filled out");
      return false;
      }
    }
</script>
```

The form itself:

```
<form action="some_file.php" method="post" id="signup_form" name="signup_form" onsubmit="return formSubmit()">
```

But all this does is if the tname field empty, it will return an alert but as soon as the user hits ok, the form then redirects to some_file.php. What have I missed here?

The submit button:

```
<a href="" onclick="return formSubmit(); return false" class="purplebutton">Signup</a>
```

So what have I missed? How do I avoid this in the future?

Comment: There is no need for formSubmit to try to submit the form!  Just perform the validation checks and return `true` if you want the submission to proceed or `false` otherwise.  Also, you do not need to check of x == null

Comment: On the other hand you probably need to also check that the user has not just pressed space a few times and then submitted.  More than that, I think you need to trim the input before sending it.  I have updated my solution to cover both the possibility that you only want the check for spaces and that you want to send the trimmed input back to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

---

```
function formSubmit()
{
    var x=document.forms["signup_form"]["tname"].value;
    if (x=="")
    {
         alert("First name must be filled out");
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

**Changes made to your code: **
- There is no need for formSubmit to try to submit the form!  Just perform the validation checks and return `true` if you want the submission to proceed or `false` otherwise.

- Also you do not need to check for the `x == null` case.  If the textbox is empty, its value will be "".
- What might be needed though is a check that x does not just contain spaces.  If you do not care about supporting older browsers you can use the new Javascript trim function.  If you care about backwards compatibility, either try one of the many javascript libraries that offer `trim` or the following:

---

```
function formSubmit()
{
    var x=document.forms["signup_form"]["tname"].value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    if (x=="")
    {
         alert("First name must be filled out");
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

If I just wanted to avoid submitting spaces I would have left the `var x=` bit as it was and added the replace in the check making it `if(x.replace(/\s/g, '') == "")`.  However, I also want to trim the input so that if the user enters " user1" or "user1 " the form will send "user1".

You can see the three different versions versions working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9LPfb/2/
http://jsfiddle.net/9LPfb/3/
http://jsfiddle.net/9LPfb/6/

Answer (score 3):

You have the wrong execution of statememts. You are submitting the form before validating. Move this statement below the if statement

```
document.getElementById("signup_form").submit();
```

further to this. you are calling `formSubmit()` at two places, `form` tag and `a` tag doing it once is fine.

UPDATED CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
    function formSubmit()
    {

    var x=document.forms["signup_form"]["tname"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("First name must be filled out");
      return false;
      }
      document.getElementById("signup_form").submit();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="some_file.php" method="post" id="signup_form" name="signup_form" onsubmit="return formSubmit()">
        <input type="text" name="tname" />
        <a href="" onclick="return formSubmit(); return false" class="purplebutton">Signup</a>
</body>
</html>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/6tyMx/)

Comment: im now using: `<script>
  function formSubmit()
  {
  var x=document.forms["signup_form"]["tname"].value;
  if (x==null || x=="")
    {
    alert("First name must be filled out");
    return false;
    }
    document.getElementById("signup_form").submit();
  }
 </script>`

Comment: @muqman: you might want to accept this as answer and may be upvote too :)

Comment: i upvoted it but I marked another person's as the answer as I tried it out first and it worked, sorry, i wish i could mark them all as the answer!

Answer (score 1):

in your function just remove this line

```
 document.getElementById("signup_form").submit();
```

and add it after the `if` condition

or rewrite the function like the one below

```
function formSubmit()
    {
    var x=document.forms["signup_form"]["tname"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("First name must be filled out");
      return false;
      }else
         return true;
    }
```

Comment: i added it after the if: `<script>
  function formSubmit()
  {
  var x=document.forms["signup_form"]["tname"].value;
  if (x==null || x=="")
    {
    alert("First name must be filled out");
    return false;
    }
    document.getElementById("signup_form").submit();
  }
 </script>` still not working...

Answer (score 1):

you have problem with your program flow .
do validation before the submitting form.
there is no use of validating after submitting, i think you have mistakenly made it.
just submit after validation.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
function formSubmit() {

    var x=document.forms["signup_form"]["tname"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("First name must be filled out");
      return false;
    }
   else {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already had all the code. It was becos of wrong execution.

```
<script>
    function formSubmit()
    {
        var x=document.forms["signup_form"]["tname"].value;
        if (!x){
              alert("First name must be filled out");
              return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>


<form action="some_file.php" method="post" id="signup_form" name="signup_form">
<a href="" onclick="return formSubmit();" class="purplebutton">Signup</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Contact Form

```
  function empty()  {   
     var x,y;

         x = document.forms["ff"]"name"].value; 
         y = document.forms["ff"]["surname"].value;

      if(x=="" ||x==null){
        alert("Enter your name");
        return false;
      }else if(y==""){
        alert("Enter your surname");
        return false;
      }else{
       alert('Data is sending');
       return true;
      } 
   };
```

In the html:

```
  <form method="POST" action="formdata.php" name="ff"onsubmit="return empty()">
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>Enter Your Name : <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="30" size="40" id="na" ></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Enter Your Surname : <input type="text" name="surname" maxlength="30" size="40" id="sna"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="submit" name="formsubmit" value="submit" >
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I indented your code, next time try to format your answers properly so you'll (probably) avoid downvotes